# jQuery/SASS hover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass

I am trying to implement a hover such that when I hover over a div, a class is activated. Below is my code.

```js
$("#page0").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('.dot-nav--link');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass('.dot-nav--link');
  }
  );
```

```css
.dot-nav--link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate(-120%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #111;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s;
}
.dot-nav--link:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 8px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#page0{
height: 80vw;
background: url("smarthome.JPG") no-repeat top center fixed;
background-size:cover;
margin-bottom: -9em;
}
```

I have no idea why this is not working. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the `.` from your `addClass()` and `removeClass()` calls, ie. `.addClass('dot-nav--link');`. Voting to close as a typo. Also note that it's *far* better to perform styling changes on the hover event in CSS directly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I removed it and it did not solve the issue

Comment: Are you sure? It works fine given your limited code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/jrsmcudb/. Note that the layout goes haywire on hover due to the fragmented CSS.

Comment: $ is not defined usually means Jquery is not loaded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `.`

```
$("#page0").hover(
  function () {
$(this).addClass('dot-nav--link');
  }, 
 function () {
$(this).removeClass('dot-nav--link');
 });
```